# Regex simple phone validation with JQuery-validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

I have a simple contact form. I need a specific regex expression for the phone number. User can type between 5-15 characters. Space, -, + and digits are allowed. I have used the below pattern but it doesn't meet my needs.

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    'phone',
    function (value, element, params) {
      return (
        this.optional(element) ||
        /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/.test(value)
      );
    },
    'Bitte nur erlaubte Zeichen eingeben: [0-9], +, -'
  );
```

Comment: What does "doesn't meet my needs" mean? The regex works https://regex101.com/r/bIxPK3/1

Comment: in my form I am gettin no error with this expression `01729863834jkjj` @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a start `^` and end `$`

https://regex101.com/r/bIxPK3/4

```js
const re = /^\+?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})$/;

function testPhone(value) {
  return re.test(value)
}

console.log(testPhone("01729863834jkjj"))
console.log(testPhone("(555)-555-5553"))
console.log(testPhone("555 555 5553"))
console.log(testPhone("+555 555 5553"))
console.log(testPhone("+001 555 1234"))
```

Comment: I seems working. But I like to use space, +, - as well

Comment: Where do you need space + and -  ?

Comment: + only at beginning as optional, space and - between the digits

Comment: See update. I just added a \+?

Comment: Wait wait, The previous one seems working prefect. This one `/^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){6,}$/`